# Transparent background for button

Tags: android, button, android-button, android-attributes

I need to set transparent background for my button, but only background, not all button.
I've tried:

```
android:background=""
android:background="null"
```

and background changed on transparent, but i've got an error:

```
Error: String types not allowed (at 'background' with value '').
```

Comment: `android:background="#AARRGGBB"` where AA is your alpha channel. Set this to `00` to be transparent.

Comment: Matt Clark  +1 , android:background ="#00000000"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type of this attribute value should be color, so use buildin attribute for transparent background with color value:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 19):

Material Ripple effect with transparent background [some Info](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Ripple-Animation)

```
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For example

> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
>     android:text="@string/add"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:textSize="18sp"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>     android:textColor="@color/fab_dark"
>     android:id="@+id/btnOkFood"
>     android:layout_gravity="right" />
> ```

With appcompat v7 this is supported for API => 11. It's a little better than a transparent background only because give a feedback of touch.

Comment: requires higher API version

Comment: Could you add an explanation and for example link to a documentation, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:background="@null"`